# Convert date from file in Perl

Tags: perl

On my program, I need to open my text file. Next I need to find date and convert. I don't know how to convert date with my code. Now in result I have mm / dd / yyyy. I'd like to change it to dd-mm-yyyy. Is it possible to do it with my code. How should I fix it?

```
#my program
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

open my $file, 'file.txt' or die "Error\n";
my $re = qr/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,4}/i;  #mm/dd/yyyy
#my $re = qr/\d{1,2}-\d{1,3}/i; #postcode     
while(my $fh = <$file>) {
    if (my @match = $fh =~ /$re/g){;
        say for @match;   
    }     
}
```

```
#my file.txt
Today is 03.02.2020. Tommorow will be 03.03.2020.
```

Comment: In `my $re = qr/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,4}/i;` the `i` at the end serve no purpose -- digits do not have _upper_ or _lower_ case. Your date in file is in form **dd-dd-dddd**, but regular expression looks for date in form of **dd/dd/d[ddd]** (year normally represented by 2 or 4 digits).

Answer (score 0):

To get the results of a match captured, you need to write parentheses around the parts you want to keep:

```
my $re = qr/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,4})/i;  #mm/dd/yy
```

Also, your sample file.txt separates the components with dots and not slashes, so you need either change the file or the regular expression.

Answer (score -2):

**Goal:** 
substitute in file all dates represented in form 'dd.mm.yyyy' to 'dd-mm-yyyy'

**Errors:**
In OP's code regex is *tuned* to date format 'dd/mm/yyyy' what does not match data in input file 'dd.mm.yyyy'

**Procedure:**
open file, read file line by line, substitute date in 'dd.mm.yyyy' format to 'dd-mm-yyyy' format in each line all occurrances, output result to console, close the file, done

**Note:**
OP outputs date by one digit on each line to console -- definitely not what he intended [corrected], to make in place substitute in input file the code should be modified or see *one liner* provided.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

# Uncomment bellow to read from file
# my $filename = 'file.txt';

# open my $file, '<', $filename
        # or die "Error\n";

# NOTE:
#   In provided file you have dates in following format
#       03.02.2020
#   but in question you refer to
#       03/02/2020
#   The code adjusted accordingly, substitution applies 
#   only to dates matching re format in line (no need for 'if')

while(<DATA>) {             # replace DATA with $file to read from a file
    chomp;                  # snip eol
    s/(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,4})/$1-$2-$3/g;       # substitute all date 0ccurrences in line
    say;   
}

__DATA__
#my file.txt
Today is 03.02.2020. Tommorow will be 03.03.2020.
```

Output

```
#my file.txt
Today is 03-02-2020. Tommorow will be 03-03-2020.
```

Comment: Code snippets with no explanation are of no help to the person asking the question or anyone else reading this. Please stop.

Comment: @Ether - Is comments in the code not sufficient? Then what should be explained? `\d` is any digit, `$1`-`$3` captured match, `say` prints content of `$_` (which represents read line in this case), `__DATA__` is data-block where the data is read from (instead of a file).  You puzzle me with 5 lines of code. It should be obvious even to perl code beginner.

Comment: @PolarBear It's not the code that needs to be explained, but the intent and reasoning for your suggestions. People learn nothing from copy pasting a code snippet that only has a chance of being what they needed, without any context that would help them make that decision.

Comment: @Grinnz -- then why you did not provide your answer to the OP? I would like to see how you would put it in _explained form_. The question was **I'd like to change it to dd-mm-yyyy. How should I fix it?** -- and code with comments demonstrates it.

Comment: @Grinnz -- `s/(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,4})/$1-$2-$3/g;       # substitute all date occurrences in line` -- states the intent _substitute all date occurrences_

Comment: @PolarBear Why do you suggest that approach? (I agree with it, by the way, but your post doesn't say.) Since the OP is ambiguous, as they often are, what use cases would this not work for? Remember that SO answers are not just for the questioner but for people with the same or similar problems later. I have not submitted an answer because I don't have any more specific solution than the two posted without more information from the OP.

Comment: @Grinnz -- because this approach in my opinion is the closest to OP's judging by his code (although printing 3 digits on separate line clearly not what he intended). His sentence **Next I need to find date and convert.** gives me a clue that he wants change format of the date, but he is not specific if he wants to save it in the file, and as he outputs to console I assumed that my code should output to console.

Comment: @Grinnz -- OP's question is too obscure and I do understand that he has some issues to put it clearly in English (I guess the guy is Polish). I am not mind reader but try my best to understand what the person wants. There is not guaranty that a lot of _English words_ in explanation will reach future readers, most population of the planet speaks other languages than English (China and India represent almost half planet's population). Note: just for information my native language is not English.

Comment: @PolarBear see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange

Comment: In other words: questions and answers are expected to be in English, and the site cannot hope to provide information in all languages of possible relevance, it is still better to provide it in English than not at all (I appreciate that it is not your native language).

Comment: @Grinnz -- did the question was in English? The answer is _yes_. Are the comments in the code was in English? The answer is _yes_. Is OP's native language is English? The answer is _no_. Did OP expressed himself clearly in English? The answer is _no_. Is my native language is English? The answer is _no_. Did we violate the policy? The answer is _no_. What was your point?

Comment: @Grinnz -- My point is that English became international language (although I think that it may change in near future with rise of China on scientific ground). Many people for whom English is not native use it for international communication and mostly due science and programming particularly. I came from country where is nationalists try _enforce_ their native language for almost 30 years but without success. In my humble opinion by doing so they isolate their nation from the world -- with population of about 18 million more than 50% speaks/understands Russian language.

Comment: I witnessed a case when in 1990-th at my University they form 2 groups who was educated in their own language, they was _inventing_ new Kazakh terms in Oil exploration field. When these students graduated nobody wanted take them as employees as nobody was understanding the language they spoke. In the end these students had _to re-educate_ themselves to use Russian or English terminology. Government needs to offer something to replace Russian movies, art,  literature, science books and countless other things before people will see a reason in it.

Comment: One more point _Math_ or _Music_ does not have association with any particular language (although Math adopted Arabic representation of digits). As _Music_ as _Math_ is understood around the world. Same should apply to _Programming_ -- the code should be able to read by any interested person, but comments in particular language will be understood only by a few.

Comment: Again, explaining the code itself is not the problem. The purpose and relevance of code to a particular reader (the OP, or the many other people who will read it later) must be explained to give context to how the code should be used. The code itself cannot do this. My point with the link is just that English does not solve this for everyone, but it is expected and better than not providing any context.

Comment: @Grinnz -- Is an explanation of form: open file, read line by line from a file, look in line for a date in format 'dd.dd.dd[dd]' and substitute it with 'dd-dd-dd[dd]' (digits in [] are optional), when no lines left close the file, will be sufficient?

Comment: @Grinnz -- I could do it a different way: read whole file at once, look for date in 'dd.dd.dd[dd]' format and substitute it to 'dd-dd-dd[dd]'. I could obscure the code written all this in one code line (even one liner command).

Comment: @PolarBear What you are explaining is what you're doing. What I'm talking about the explanation of *why*.

Comment: @Grinnz -- because OP doesn't know how to do it, because he asked for a help.

Comment: Why you suggest this method instead of another, not why you answered.

Comment: @Grinnz -- because this is easiest/fastest/simplest way to accomplish desired result. Why we do anything? Because we have _goal_ and we want reach it _fastest/easiest/less expencive_ way.

Answer (score -2):

If the goal to change date format in file then this can be achieved with following one liner

```
perl -0777 -pe "s/\b(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{2,4})\b/$1-$2-$3/g" -i file.txt
```

Options:

- -0777 read file at once
- -pe execute script in "..." and print out result
- -i do replacement in place (original file modified to desired result)

Note:

MS Windows assume the script to be wrapped into `"perl script"`, UNIX systems assume the script to be wrapped into `'perl script'`.

`\b` can be omitted if there is not strict requirements for *date* be separated by punctuation.

*Attention:*

Please make a copy of original file just in case you make a mistake.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208896/discussion-on-answer-by-polar-bear-convert-date-from-file-in-perl).